# Redirect department but exlude one page from the redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following rule which redirects all pages - except php and php3 pages - from the info department to a new server where we are hosting or new website:

```
RedirectMatch ^/info/(?!.*php3?)(.*) http://www2.example.com/info/$1
```

I need to exclude the page `http://www2.example.com/info/test.shtml` from the above rule so that it does NOT redirect to our new site and the page displays from the old site - Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#redirect if does not end with php/3 or is not test.shtml
RedirectMatch ^/info/(?!(.*php3?|test\.shtml))(.*) http://www2.example.com/info/$1
```